# Pass LaTeX variable from DocumentClass file to class

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing, class-options

DocumentClass MWE...

```
\documentclass{testclass}

\begin{document}

    \outputdirpath{../auxil}

    \begin{minted}{php}
    <?php
        $x = 1;
        if($x=1){
            echo "x=1";
        } else {
            echo "x=" . $x;
        }
    ?>
    \end{minted}

\end{document}
```

testclass MWE...

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2022/12/02]

\newcommand*{\outputdirpath}[1]{outputdir=#1}

%\PassOptionsToPackage{outputdir=../auxil}{minted}
\PassOptionsToPackage{\outputdirpath}{minted}
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{minted}

\LoadClass[11pt]{article}
```

If I run as these files stand, the *\outputdirpath* is not set and Minted package does not find the *.pyg* file in it's compiled path. If I swap the hidden *\PassOptionsToPackage* class file line with the one above it, all works as expected.

I want to load Minted package with the *outputdir=../* option from a class.

As an aside, I'm also seeking a relatively recent book on class/package development.

TIA!

Comment: you need to make it an option when minted is loaded so either use a  class option not a command in the preamble or delay loading minted in `\AtBeginDocument` so it is after your command can pass option to the package

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have key=value options for a document class you have different options. The two I'd choose from are:

1. the mechanism built into recent versions of the LaTeX kernel
2. the `expkv-opt` package (disclaimer: I'm its author)

With both of the following two examples you can use `\documentclass[mintedpathoneback=../auxil]{testclass}`.

## LaTeX kernel

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2022/12/02]

\DeclareKeys{mintedpathoneback .store = \testclass@minted@outputdir}
\ProcessKeyOptions

\LoadClass[11pt]{article}
\ifx\testclass@minted@outputdir\@empty
  \RequirePackage{minted}
\else
  \RequirePackage[outputdir=\testclass@minted@outputdir]{minted}
\fi
```

## `expkv-opt`

This also uses `expkv-def` for a key=value interface to define your keys

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2022/12/02]

\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{testclass}{store mintedpathoneback = \testclass@minted@outputdir}
\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{testclass}

\LoadClass[11pt]{article}
\ifx\testclass@minted@outputdir\@empty
  \RequirePackage{minted}
\else
  \RequirePackage[outputdir=\testclass@minted@outputdir]{minted}
\fi
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `.store = \macro` and `\ifx\macro\empty ...` over `\DeclareKeys{mintedpathoneback .code = \PassOptionsToPackage{outputdir=#1}{minted}}`?

Comment: @mbert if you need the macro for another purpose yes, else no. Provided your macro behaves nicely. It could result in different behaviour depending on how `minted` parses its options, but since it's using `kvoptions` it makes no difference.

Comment: Oh, very nice: thanks! I don't have enough SE street cred to upvote, but I tried. +1 for the recent version of LaTeX kernel feeedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Carlisle for adjusting my head towards a solution. Code now works by changing the DocumentClass MWE line to...

```
\documentclass[mintedpathoneback]{testclass}
```

...and rearranging the class file to...

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2022/12/02]

\DeclareOption{mintedpathoneback}{\newcommand\outputdirpath{../auxil}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[11pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[outputdir=\outputdirpath]{minted}
```

It would be nice to be able to declare *mintedpathoneback=../* in DocumentClass options and then have class pick up the path variable but for now I'm allowing my two brain cells to give up trying. They were quite useless at it this evening. If someone came up with a better solution I would flag that as the answer.